# AttributeError: 'gevent._local.local' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, keras

I have a keras Sequential model which works perfectly fine during model training, But when I am trying to run model.predict command on trained model,

I am getting following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/program/predictor.py", line 69, in predict
    a=model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1456, in predict
    self._make_predict_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 378, in _make_predict_function
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 323, in __setattr__
    super(Network, self).__setattr__(name, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1215, in __setattr__
    if not _DISABLE_TRACKING.value:
  File "src/gevent/local.py", line 408, in gevent._local.local.__getattribute__

AttributeError: 'gevent._local.local' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I have searched for this error but couldn't found any solution. 
Does anyone know any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reason for this error:

My docker container automatically installs latest keras version which got changed to 2.3.0(New stable version) which was not available till last week so my container was working perfectly fine previously. Keras new stable version : 2.3.0 might have some issue with Gevent which was causing this conflict.

**I uninstalled keras and installed 2.2.5 version which resolved the error.**

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras==2.2.5
```

Comment: Any solution on keras 2.3.0 ?

Comment: Please check the answer of Francois Chollet in this thread if this is useful:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13346